# ¿Por qué aparece el error Cannot find module './routes/index.js'?

Tags: nodejs, express

Tengo el siguiente código en `ExpressJS`:

El siguiente fichero es `app.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const logger_morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

const indexRoutes = require('./routes/index.js');

//settings
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

//middlewares
app.use(logger_morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

//routes
app.use('/', indexRoutes);

app.listen(app.get('port'), () =>{
    console.log('server on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

El siguiente fichero es `index.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

/* router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello');
}); */

module.exports = router;
```

Y así es la estructura de la carpeta raíz del proyecto respecto a estos dos ficheros:

> Raíz
>   --src
>   -----app.js
>   --routes
>   -----index.js

Entonces, no entiendo el porqué del siguiente error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './routes/index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\vycto\Desktop\crud-express-mongo\src\app.js:7:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

Comment: Hola @Schopenhauer,
Lo que ocurre es que lo estas indicando como si fuera desde la raíz, tendrías que sustituirlo por `const indexRoutes = require('../routes/index.js');`.
Un saludo

Comment: ¡Tienes toda la razón! Gracias por la respuesta, la postearé como solución en una respuesta mía, pero si tu lo haces antes de que pueda colocar la solución a mi propia respuesta obviamente de la concederé.
@planta4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se está indicando el directorio raíz donde se encuentra app.js (`src`), pero necesitamos indicar el directorio raíz del proyecto para hacer referencia a la carpeta `routes`, para esto sustituimos:

```
const indexRoutes = require('./routes/index.js');
```

por:

```
const indexRoutes = require('../routes/index.js');
```

Fuente: la respuesta de @planta4.